# Month in Footer

Tags: header-footer

I'm creating a photo book and want the month on the outside (away from binding) bottom corner of each page.

It seems the package `fancyhdr` wants to put the same footer on each page.

How do I get it to let me put a different footer on each page, and to alternate which side of the page the footer is on depending on the binding?

Comment: How is the month determined? Do you have some special command that you set the appropriate month (or date)? Please share what you currently have so we can make more educated guesses as to what's happening. Well, help us avoid the guessing game, really.

Comment: I have a python script generating the Latex code, that will figure out the month by looking at EXIF data.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of the python script output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to switch easily between the left/right side of the headers/footers use `twoside` mode in the document. Then define the month using a macro that you have control over to change as needed.

The example/template code below uses this approach, setting `\currentmonth` on the `L`eft/`R`ight of every `E`ven/`O`dd page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\currentmonth}% Footer on outside (LE = Left Even; RO = Right Odd)
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Center footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\currentmonth}{}% 

\begin{document}

\centering

% JANUARY
\renewcommand{\currentmonth}{January}

\includegraphics[page=1,scale=0.5]{example-image-letter-numbered}

\newpage

% FEBRUARY
\renewcommand{\currentmonth}{February}

\includegraphics[page=2,scale=0.5]{example-image-letter-numbered}

% ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to fill header and footer with changing text is to use marks. LaTeX offers a left and a right mark. You can set them with `\markboth` or `\markright`, and then retrieve the first right mark on a page with `\rightmark` and the last left mark with `\leftmark`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\rightmark--\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=1]{example-image-duck}%
\markboth{january}{january}

\includegraphics[page=2]{example-image-duck}%
\markboth{march}{march}

\includegraphics[page=3]{example-image-duck}%
\markboth{june}{june}

\includegraphics[page=4]{example-image-duck}%
\markboth{july}{july}

\includegraphics[page=5]{example-image-duck}%
\markboth{march}{march}

\includegraphics[page=6]{example-image-duck}%
\markboth{june}{june}

\end{document}
```

[image]